# ¿Como obtener los archivos .jpeg de un directorio?

Tags: c#

Como puedo obtener solo los archivos .jpeg de mi directorio, actualmente tengo un codigo que seria el siguiente:

```
var directoriosE = Directory.GetFiles(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\"+folder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => "jpeg".Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)));
```

Ese codigo deberia ejecutar la obtencion de los archivos con la extension .jpeg, solo que nunca eh trabajado con linq y me gustaria saber como recuperar la informacion en formato de numero de los archivos con esa extension de ese directorio.

Antes lo estaba haciendo directamente con el puro `.GetFiles("Ruta")` y lo obtenia de la siguiente forma `archivos = archivos + directoriosE.Length;` y si me daba la cantidad de archivos, pero me da la de todos los tipos de archivos de la carpeta ahora me gustaria saber la forma de limitar eso.

Comment: no deberia ser al reves? Path.GetExtension(s).Contains("jpeg")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias usar

```
string folder = "...";

sting[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

como veras se define "*.jpg" para traer solo de esta extension

[Directory.GetFiles (String, String, SearchOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)